"import torch" giving an import error: from torch._C import
I set up a torch virtual environment in ubuntu and installed torch itself with the following commands:
(torchgpu) $ pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
(torchgpu) $ pip install --upgrade opencv-python opencv-contrib-python
(torchgpu) $ pip install --upgrade torch torchvision torchaudio

When I try to verify that torch is installed correctly, I get this:
(torchgpu) $ python
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/USER/venvs/torchgpu/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 239, in <module>
    from torch._C import *  # noqa: F403
ImportError: /home/USER/venvs/torchgpu/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/../../nvidia/cusparse/lib/libcusparse.so.12: undefined symbol: __nvJitLinkAddData_12_1, version libnvJitLink.so.12


it seems it need some C/C++ library libnvJitLink.so.12 but it doesn't have some function. Maybe it needs to install/update some library (using apt on Ubuntu) OR maybe it needs to compile it from source code using C/C++ compiler. Did you get any error message when you install modules?

@furas no error message when installing modules, it seems to be specific to torch

without error messages it is hard to say what can be the problem. You may have to search on internet undefined symbol: __nvJitLinkAddData_12_1, version libnvJitLink.so. Maybe someone had this problem before.

found with Google: Undefined symbol: __nvJitLinkAddData_12_1, version libnvJitLink.so.12 - PyTorch Forums

ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/lib/../../nvidia/cusparse/lib/libcusparse.so.12: undefined symbol: __nvJitLinkAddData_12_1, version libnvJitLink.so.12 · Issue #111469 · pytorch/pytorch
